# How to read dataset from file and plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab

This is pretty simple yet I am facing some problems with handling data-types in Matlab.

The below would create a simple array.

```
l=[]
for i=1:10
   # do something here
   # i = i* i;
end
plot(l) # would happily plot it
```

In the below code, `data` is loaded into workspace from file containing strings each line. each line is taken as each row, and data as `String`.

```
numbers=[]
index = 1;
split_data = regexp(data, ' ', 'split');
for eachLine=split_data
    eachLine = eachLine{:}
    num = eachLine(3) # this is the value I need
    numbers(index) = num
    index = index + 1
end
plot(numbers)
```

That's it. That's what I want to do. Extract a number from string, store in a matrix, plot it. However after iterations, the `numbers` object is appearing as integer and not a vector/ matrix!!

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`numbers = [numbers num];`

in place of

`numbers(index) = num`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have a cell array of strings with each line having a single string and in each line the 3rd word is a number.
You might like to change your code to :

```
% example data variable
data={'air is 3 4 all';'lov3 K 9 s';'this is 7 o''clock'};

split_data = regexp(data, ' ', 'split');
len=length(split_data);
numbers=zeros(1, len);

for index=1:len
    line = split_data{index};
    num = line(3); % this is the value I need
    numbers(index) = str2double(num);
end
plot(numbers)
```